# How to stop an image to be responsive?

Tags: html, css

I wanna make a image responsive but only till to an specific width of the screen. Say if the user starts from 300px width to enlarge the screen the image should be responsive and should grow with the screen width. Once a width of 1440 px is achieved the image should stop with adapting the scale. Imagine a image in the following code

```
<style>

    .left-main {

        flex: 30%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .icon-position{
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-left: 33.195%;
        width: 61%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
<div class = "left-main">
        <img src="images/Developer_Icon.svg" class="icon-position" width="178" height="180">
</div>
```

At an specific display width the image should stop to be "responsive" and should hold the last size which the image had. How can I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max-width` css property. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

```
.icon-position{
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-left: 33.195%;
        width: 61%;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 1400px; // anyvalue here
    }
```

Comment: Sry, I think it was not clear enough written from me. The image should have at this point of the screen width a fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

```
.image-position{
    max-width: Enter width of your choice here;
}
```

Max width in css is used to define the maximum width an element can have. The element will stop becoming wider after the max-width is achieved.

Thanks

Comment: Sry, I think it was not clear enough written from me. The image should have at this point of the screen width a fixed position.

Comment: Ohh I can still help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways. First, check what is width of image in specific window width and then use this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) { 
    .image {
    width: 600px; //define image width
                  //here set all other parameters, fixed position etc.
    }
}
```

Second way is to use JavaScript. When window is in needed width then get image's width and write it into style. If you need, I can add JS code for this.

Comment: But with this code the image still moves relative to the screen. The width is fixed yes but the general position of the image not.

Comment: `@media screen and` property changed to `min-width: 1440px`

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .left-main {
        flex: 30%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .icon-position{
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-left: 33.195%;
        width: 61%;
        height: auto;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    .icon-position {
       width: 700px; /*Instead of width: 700px, you can define you own desired width of the image, after 1440px screen size.*/
    }
</style>
<div class="left-main">
        <img src="images/Developer_Icon.svg" class="icon-position" width="178" height="180">
</div>
```